# Monorepo(turborepo) template with sitecore-jss

Tags: jss

Since Sitecore and Vercel announced partnership, I'm curious is there any plans for the official template for sitecore-jss SDK with Vercel's [turborepo](https://turbo.build/repo/docs) support?
Or at least some guidance how to do it in a proper way?